# Into which technique would this algorithm fall into? Brute Force or Greedy?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, greedy, brute-force

I have an algorithm that I am not sure whether to classify as a greedy algorithm or a brute force algorithm.

```
while(true) {
            int n = 0;
            int d = 0;
              int r = 0;
              int outcome = 0;
            
            n = scan.nextInt();
            d = scan.nextInt();
            r = scan.nextInt();

            if ( n + d + r == 0) break;

            int[] morning = new int[n];
            int[] afternoon = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                morning[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                afternoon[i] = -scan.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int sum = morning[i] + (-afternoon[i]) - d;
                if (sum > 0) outcome += sum * r;
            }
            System.out.printf("%d\n", outcome);
        }
```

I feel like it is most likely greedy, not completely certain.

Comment: As others mentioned, the code as written is neither brute force nor greedy. It's simply consuming all data and outputting a result. If you want help making it do something else, you should modify your question. State *in words* what you want the program to do. Remember, all we know about your problem is what you tell us. There is no Vulcan mind-meld.

Comment: Is this a problem from a programming contest?

Comment: @PabloH It is. The optimize bus problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Greedy algorithm is one that limits the amount of work it has to do by making certain assumptions about data values it receives along the way.  Your code is definitely not greedy, as it is going to perform the same logic on every value in the incoming data set, regardless of the specific values involved.

An algorithm is Brute Force if it takes a naive approach to solving a problem that will consume considerably more resources (time and/or memory) than another algorithm that is able to limit resource usage by being more clever in its approach to the problem.

So if your algorithm is Brute Force or not, IMO, comes down to if there could be a more efficient way to process the same data and arrive at the same answer.  Looking at your code, it isn't obvious to me how there could be a more efficient way to do what it is doing.  It seems to me that you will need to process every set of values in the data set, regardless of the particular values involved.  For that reason, I don't think your algorithm could be said to be Brute Force.

It could be that the incoming data has characteristics that would allow you to optimize your approach. For example, say that you know that once the `sum` value that you compute for an entry is negative, all of the remaining data values will produce a `sum` value that is negative as well.  In that case, you could stop processing data as soon as you see a negative value for `sum`.  In this case, your algorithm would be Brute Force vs the algorithm that stops processing upon seeing a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

So at first glance, and without further information, it does not seem to me that this algorithm uses greedy or brute force techniques.

By definition a greedy algorithm makes decisions at each step by choosing the locally optimal choice, with the hope of finding a global optimum, and a brute force algorithm tries every possible solution to a problem, in order to find the correct solution.

It doesn't appear that that piece of code does either of those things.

Comment: Any idea how I could make it work as brute force? I want both my arrays to undergo every single permutation possible but not quite sure how to make that happen.

Comment: You need to explain what the objective of your problem is, before expecting any useful help...

Comment: @pgeadas my objective is that I have two arrays, morning[i] and afternoon[i]. My aim is to have a loop that creates an addition combination of all between all elements of both arrays.

Comment: If what I understand is correct, once the arrays are filled, you'd want two nested for loops, within which you do all possible sums. Is that it?

Comment: @justcivah Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: You'll need a loop that iterates over the elements of 'morning', inside which you insert another loop that iterates over the elements of 'afternoon'. Within this last cycle you can carry out the necessary checks.